# Nikon D3300 Headphone output?

Tags: audio

How can I from my Nikon d3300 get a headphone output? Im using rode micro I would like it not to be a huge box or super long cable.

This is my first preference. Start in the upper left. (mic)
[image: This is my first preference. Start in the upper left. (mic)]

This is my second preference. Start in the upper left. (mic)
[image: This is my second preference. Start in the upper left. (mic)]

REG/rode_videomicro_compact_on_camera.html

Comment: Nikon d3300:https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1266500-DEMO/nikon_1532_d3300_dslr_camera_with.html

Rode Micro:https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1183909-REG/rode_videomicro_compact_on_camera.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microphone outputs are typically very low level and have only enough output to drive a sensitive preamp, not headphones.  To drive headphones you need an amplified output.  According to a variety of sources, the D3300 does not have a headphone jack, which means you have to provide a separate amplifier, which means you have to provide one, and the power to drive it, and the cable to connect to it.  I suspect the best solution would be a battery-powered preamp that receives your mic output and then delivers two amplified outputs: line level for your D3300 input jack and phones-level for your headphones.